# Print only `Names` column from `docker-container ls -la` output

Tags: linux, bash, docker

When issuing the `docker container ls -la` command, the output looks like this:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND               CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
a67f0c2b1769   busybox   "tail -f /dev/null"   26 seconds ago   Up 25 seconds             recursing_liskov
```

I'd like to get only the container's name present in the `Names` column.

My idea was to use bash to reverse the columns in the command output so as to get the `Names` column in first position and cut the name of container.

This is what I tried:

```sh
sudo docker container ls -la | rev |tail -n +2 | tr -s ' ' |  cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

However this does not give the expected result and I get the following error:

```
rev: stdin: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

I'm stuck as I don't know how to handle this error. Can it be fixed to obtain the result I expect ? Or is there any other way to obtain my result ?

Comment: If you want to get a particular column, just grab it with `awk`.  eg `cmd | awk '{print $NF}'` to print the final column.  Your `awk` may or may not handle the multibyte character any better than `rev`, though.

Comment: You might consider using a richer programming language (I'm partial to Python for this sort of thing) and a [native Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/), rather than trying to scrape the `docker ps` output.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rather than playing around with a default output, just print exactly what you are looking for from start. Most docker sub-commands accept a `--format` option which will take a [go template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) expression to specify what you exactly want.

In your case, I believe the following command should give what you are looking for:

```
$ docker container ls -la --format "{{.Names}}"
recursing_liskov
```

Of course, you can add more columns if you wish, in whatever order best suits your needs. You can easily get a list of all keys available with something like:

```
$ docker container ls -la --format "{{json .}}" | jq
{
  "Command": "\"tail -f /dev/null\"",
  "CreatedAt": "2022-01-15 23:43:54 +0100 CET",
  "ID": "a67f0c2b1769",
  "Image": "busybox",
  "Labels": "",
  "LocalVolumes": "0",
  "Mounts": "",
  "Names": "recursing_liskov",
  "Networks": "bridge",
  "Ports": "",
  "RunningFor": "20 minutes ago",
  "Size": "0B (virtual 1.24MB)",
  "State": "running",
  "Status": "Up 20 minutes"
}
```

Here is an example just to illustrate using some of the fields:

```
$ docker container ls -la --format "container {{.Names}} is in state {{.State}} and has ID {{.ID}}"
container recursing_liskov is in state running and has ID a67f0c2b1769
```

Some random references out of several I used:

- https://devcoops.com/filter-output-of-docker-image-ls/
- https://windsock.io/customising-docker-cli-output/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question, but if you just want to rearrange the order of the columns, you can use `awk` and its `printf` function. It's not the most elegant way, but depending on your use case, it might work for you.

For instance, you can use the following for a two columns output command:

```
cmd | awk '{printf ("%s\t%s\n", $1, $2)}'
```

In the same fashion, you could do:

```
docker container ls -la | awk '{printf ("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", $8, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)}'
```

As I said, this can be considered a dirty workaround but I am not sure what your use case demands. Note that the first row with the columns name won't be as pretty as it is by default. You can fix that giving each of the elements a (max) width (`%5s` sets a width of 5).